# Where do i get the newest version of Phonegap/Cordova? (2.2.0)

Tags: cordova

How can i get the newest version of PhoneGap / Cordova

As i can see from their site, there should be a version 2.2.0 (Unreleased)

[https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project:summary-panel](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3asummary-panel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a newer version than what has been released (2.1 is the current active release) that you get [here](http://phonegap.com/download), then you need to go to [the cordova/phonegap github](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios) and download that.

EDIT: The link I provided gives you the latest version that is still being tested and isn't guaranteed to be safe.  The link Simon provides in his answer is the newest release/release candidate and is the one people should use.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It seems to me, that the version on https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios is also 2.1.0 - But is it newer than the one on the phonegap download page?

Comment: It should be the 'edge' version, as in the very latest that they are testing with.

Comment: Guys as a core PhoneGap committer I wouldn't recommend picking up the edge unless you want to help with development. Grab the lastest build or latest release candidate from the links I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The latest binary release is always available from [phonegap.com](http://phonegap.com/download#). The latest source releases are always available from [Apache.org](https://www.apache.org/dist/incubator/cordova/).

We aren't tagging 2.2.0 release candidate 1 until Monday.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

http://registry.cnpmjs.org/phonegap

```
{"_id":"phonegap","_rev":"520762","name":"phonegap","description":"PhoneGap command-line interface and node.js library.","dist-tags":{"3.5.0-0.19.23":"3.5.0-0.19.23","latest":"3.5.0-0.21.14"},
```

3.5.0-0.19.23 is the newest version.